# Why onAttach in page-mod module is not getting executed in Firefox add-on sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a Firefox add-on which uses [context-menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.11/packages/addon-kit/context-menu.html) and [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.11/packages/addon-kit/page-mod.html) modules.

This add-on adds a new menu item to the context menu when the context is input control. When the menu item is clicked, I request to the server to get some data and pushes the result to the content script which `page-mod` is using.

For some reason, `onAttach` function is not getting called. There are no errors in the console. I am not sure why it is not getting called. Here is what I am doing.

```
var data = require("self").data,
    contextMenu = require("context-menu"),
    request = require("request").Request;

var workers = [];
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: '*',
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.8.2.min.js"), data.url("varnam.js")],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        console.log("onAttach");
        workers.push(worker);
        worker.on("detach", function() {
            var index = workers.indexOf(worker);
            if (index >= 0) workers.splice(index, 1);
        });
    }
});
```

Any help to fix this issue would be great. Full code is available [here](https://github.com/navaneeth/varnam-browser-addons/blob/master/firefox/lib/main.js).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the url pattern begins with (or is just) an asterisk, then it is matched against urls with a scheme of `http`, `https` and `ftp`.

Since your test page is in the data directory its url scheme is `resource`. And that's why PageMod is not triggered.

You can add the test page url by doing something like

```
var varnam = pageMod.PageMod({ 
// blah blah
});

varnam.include.add(data.url("test.html"));
```